# How to convert pandas Dataframe to string or bytes-like object that can be used for NLTK

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

one column in pandas Dataframe contains text information, I'd like to put them together as a piece of text for further NLTK.

i.e

```
    book    lines
0   dracula The Project Gutenberg EBook of Dracula, by Br...
1   dracula \n
2   dracula This eBook is for the use of anyone anywhere a...
3   dracula almost no restrictions whatsoever. You may co...
4   dracula re-use it under the terms of the Project Guten...
```

followed by my code

```
list_of_words = [i.lower() for i in wordpunct_tokenize(data[0]['lines']) if i.lower() not in stop_words and i.isalpha()]
```

and got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-267-3bb703816dc6>", line 1, in <module>
list_of_words = [i.lower() for i in wordpunct_tokenize(data[0]['Injury_desc']) if i.lower() not in stop_words and i.isalpha()]

File "C:\Users\LIUX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\regexp.py", line 131, in tokenize
return self._regexp.findall(text)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: please provide sample `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming because you are passing a dataframe to the wordpunct_tokenize function which expects only strings or byte-like objects.

You need to iterate over all the rows and pass the line one by one to wordpunct_tokenize.

```
list_of_words = []
for line in data['lines']:
    list_of_words.extend([i.lower() for i in wordpunct_tokenize(line) if i.lower() not in stop_words and i.isalpha()])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does help!